# jar file not working for imports in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jar, twitter4j

I am following a tutorial from [AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/) on how to login to Twitter from my app.

The tutorial uses the twitter4j library, so I download it from [here](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html#download) and save the zip file to my desktop. In my project I drag the twitter4j zip file into my projects libs folder. Then I Refactor -> Rename the file from a zip to a jar (only changing the extension)

However, when I want to import the classes into my project, it does not seem to be working. I try to do

```
import twitter4j.Twitter;
```

But this option is not available. See screen grab.
Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong with this?

Also, as per the tutorial I have also just added the twitter4j-core file to the project but still imports wont seem to work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial clearly says "Download and Extract" That does not mean "Download and Rename". It means download the file and then Use a file compress/uncompress utility to extract the zipped files format. Search in the extracted files to find the relevant jar file and import that file.

```
1. Download & extract twitter4j library from twitter4j-android-2.2.6.zip (slimmed version for Android platform). Here is the direct link
```

If you uncompressed correctly then do the following

Right sure that the folder where you copied the twitter library shows up in the Lib path for the project. Right click on the project --> Select 'Properties' ---> Select 'Java Build Path' From the Left hand Menu ---> Select Libraries Tab. Review List of Libraries(expand if needed ) to see if the twitter jar files show up here.
If not Select 'Add Jar' browse to the Jar file. Add it. Refresh your project. Clean it and build. You should now be able to import twitter components.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that I did that as well. Downloaded, extracted and then added the jar files from twitter4j-core but still does not work.

Comment: Ok found the problem. Was looking in the wrong place. The correct path to the twitter4j core is /twitter4j/libs/twitter-core-XXX